# Joint distribution of mistakes of phones

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, joint-distribution

I am a bit confused with the following problem of probability:
"We select 3 phones of a sample in which we know that the 60% of them contain one mistake and the 10% contain more than one mistake. We define the variables $X$="number of phones with some mistake" and $Y$="number of products with less than two mistakes". Obtain the joint distribution table".

I have conluded from the information that $X$ is given by a binomial distribution of probability $0.7$ and $Y$ also by a binomial but with probability $0.9$. But I think I am not considering cases that are trivial and have probability zero. Maybe because the problem seems a bit ambiguous to me. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: If you could explain how you concluded $X$ follows a Binomial distribution, then we could explain what error you have made; moreover, by attempting such an explanation you might make progress towards a correct solution.  It would also be useful to explain what you make of the ambiguous characterization "__% of them contain ...": do *phones* "contain" mistakes (whatever that might mean) or do *samples of 3 phones* contain mistakes? And how do you hope to obtain the joint distribution without knowing the number of phones in the sample from which you are selecting?